# SciPy optimization algorithm of function with nonlinear constrainrs

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am seeking for a suitable SciPy (or another python library) algorithm to find the global minimum of a smooth function (it is sum of budgets in fact) with quite tough non-linear constraints.

I have already tried global opt algorithms, such as [shgo](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.shgo.html#rb2e152d227b3-3) and [basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html) with local optimizers like ['trust-constr'](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-trustconstr.html#optimize-minimize-trustconstr), ['COBYLA'](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-cobyla.html) or 'SLSQP' ad had always failed. All attemptions results are inappropriate high values or very close to my x0.
For instance, one of the dozens attemptions:

```
    def cons_J(x, *args):
        return np.ones(len(x))
    minimizer_kwargs = {'method': 'SLSQP',
                        'args': (reach, freq, DF_GROUP, MEMBER, days),
                        'constraints': cons_sqlsqp,
                        'tol': 0.01,
                        'options': {'maxiter': 15, 'disp':True},
                        'jac': cons_J}
    result = basinhopping(minimize_me_reach, x0=x0,
                  minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs,
                  niter=150, T=1500, stepsize=10000,
                  interval=40, disp=True,
                  niter_success=80, seed=350
                    )
```

Maybe hyperparameters looking too odd, but I've tried different sets, and by default too.

There is one non-linear constraint for now, which define like

```
cons_sqlsqp = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': constr_reach})
```

But later there will be 3 additional constraints.

So, any idea about suitable algorithm?

Comment: add the imports like `numpy` and also for `basinhopping` because at the moment they are not defined.

Comment: If `cons_sqlsqp` is "quite tough" then... maybe you should show it. My crystal ball is malfunctioning today

Comment: Well, I can just say that its nonlinear nature and there is too much code that I cant open due to non-disclosure agreement. 'cons_sqlsqp = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': constr_reach})'

Comment: Try `differential_evolution`, but nothing is going to save you if there's no viable solution. It's probably easier to construct if you use `NonlinearConstraint` instead of the old constraint specification.

Comment: Why 'maxiter': 15?  The SLSQP solver, in almost all cases, needs many more to get somewhat close to local optimality. Also note that global optimization is just very difficult and that basinhopping is just a heuristic. There exist excellent deterministic global solvers (but not as part of scipy).

Answer (score 1):

You could try [genetic algorithms](https://pygad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is traditionally the choice for problems that baffle the modern optimization toolkit. This will provide an approximate solution ***eventually***, but may take a very, very long time for it. Just make sure to enable elitist selection, as in this case there is a proof of convergence.

This probably answers the question in a strict sense. However, it usually is best in such cases to rework the formulation of the optimization problem, probably by choosing a different modelling approach.